# How to change table width to 100% using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like change the `table` width to `100%` if the width value defined in pixels.

I mean if the table width look like `width="500"` or `width="500px"` , then I would like replace it with `100%`.

I mean like this `width="100%"`.

Can someone help me with preg_replace.

```
$content = 'holds all my html content';
$replace = '100%';
preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$content,-1);
```

Can someone help me with the `$pattern`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not using `preg_replace`, and give an example using the DOM

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('table') as $item) {
    if(strpos($item->getAttribute('width'), '%') === false) {
        $item->setAttribute('width', '100%');
    }
}
$content = $dom->saveHTML();
```

If you want to replace all `table`'s to have a width of `100%`, remove the `if` clause.  Currently, it checks to make sure the `width` isn't percentage based.

**EDIT**

Just in case you don't want nicely formatted HTML, you can get the body content without the body tags by changing:

```
$content = $dom->saveHTML();
```

To:

```
$content = substr($dom->saveXml($body->item(0)), 6, -7);
```

So if you have

```
$content = '<table width="600px"><td>Stuff</td></table><table width="50%"><td>Stuff</td></table>';
```

You'll end up with:

```
<table width="100%"><td>Stuff</td></table><table width="50%"><td>Stuff</td></table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = '<table width=" 600 px "></table>' ;
$pattern = '/width=["\']\s*\d+\s*(px|%)\s*["\']/' ;
$own_style = 'width="100%"' ;
$new = preg_replace($pattern, $own_style, $string) ;
```

This can help you, but in case if there is no more width attributes in your HTML content.
Otherwise, if any other elements have with attribute, their `width` will be set to `100%`

So, generally it is a bad practice to use `REGEXP` for handling `HTML`.

You should use `DOM`: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php